# Учение или ученье

Tags: нормы-языка

"Ученье - свет" или "учение - свет"?

Answer (score 3):

Можно и так, и так. *Ученье* - более разговорный вариант, *учение* - более книжный. В рамках пословицы "ученье - свет, а неученье - тьма", правильно только через "ь", так как фразеологизм.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

У слов "Ученье"/"Учение" - три значения.

~1. Процесс обучения 
~2. Войсковые маневры
~3. Система взглядов на что-либо.

Оба варианта применимы ко всем трем значениям. Но при этом для первого лично я чаще слышу ученье, второе - почти всегда во множественном (в варианте - учения), третье - в форме "учение". Ну а в фразеологизме, естественно, "ученье"

Comment: "А город подумал - ученья идут...". Последние два значения не часто услышишь в разговорной речи, но когда служил в армии (2005-2006), в непосредственной речи чаще слышал "ученья".

Comment: Ну это все-таки стихи. Песня. 
Хотя, может, Вы и правы... Трудно утверждать наверняка, когда все на слух...